# Nodejs Snowflake connection - Error [NetworkError]: Network error. Could not reach Snowflake

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect snowflake, using the node.js driver found in the [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html)

```
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');

var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: 'account1',
  username: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

connection.connect(function(err, conn) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected as id: ' + connection.getId());
  }
});
```

> Error: Network error. Could not reach Snowflake.
>
> code: 401001,
>
> cause: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

[image]

Comment: You might be failing [OCSP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#ocsp-online-certificate-status-protocol) check, can you try setting it to [insecureMode](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-turn-off-OCSP-checking-in-Snowflake-client-drivers) and see if it works after?

Comment: Are you by any chance passing the region in the account parameter as well? The one for region is not needed since the account itself should be something like this: <account-locator>.<region>

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything even set NODE in debug mode.

Finally added the public SCHEMA to the createConnection object and fixed it.

So, in your case (assuming you want to connect to the PUBLIC schema):

```
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: 'account1',
  username: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1',
  region: 'us-east-1' 
  schema: 'PUBLIC
});
```