# Node.js - Network error. Could not reach Snowflake

Tags: node.js, snowflake-schema

I'm using 'snowflake-sdk',
I'm trying to connect to snowflake but keep getting

```
code:
401001
message:
'Network error. Could not reach Snowflake.'
name:
'NetworkError'
```

Here is my code:

```
const snowConnect = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: 'https://xxxxxxx.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com',
  username: username,
  password: password,
});
snowflake.configure({ insecureConnect: true });

snowConnect.connect(function (err, conn) {
  if (err) {
    debugger;
    console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected as id: ' + snowConnect.getId());
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
this.createConnection = snowflake.createConnection({
  accessUrl: 'https://xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com',
  username: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  account: 'XXxxxxxxx',
  database: 'TEST',
  role: 'ACCOUNTADMIN',
});
```

Comment: can we connect with only accessurl without account as https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/node-js/nodejs-driver-options#additional-connection-options ? as i am passing https://xxxxxxx.north-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com and it gives error

Answer (score -1):

Your code is looking correct, this seems to be due to given below:

1. Verify the Snowflake account URL: Ensure that the account URL you
   provided is correct and matches the format
   `xxxxxxx.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com`. Double-check for any
   typos or missing characters.
2. Check network connectivity: Confirm that your network connection is
   stable and not experiencing any disruptions or firewall restrictions
   that may prevent reaching the Snowflake service. You can try
   accessing the Snowflake account URL in a web browser to verify if
   you can establish a connection.
3. Confirm Snowflake credentials: Make sure the `username` and `password`
   variables contain the correct Snowflake credentials. Double-check
   for any spelling mistakes or incorrect values.
4. Verify Snowflake connectivity settings: Ensure that you have the
   appropriate network and connectivity settings for Snowflake. Review
   the Snowflake documentation and consult with your Snowflake
   administrator if needed to confirm the correct settings.
5. Test using a Snowflake client: Try connecting to Snowflake using a
   different Snowflake client, such as the Snowflake web interface or a
   dedicated Snowflake client tool. This will help determine if the
   issue is specific to your code or a broader connectivity problem.

Comment: Already tried all of that, thanks.

Comment: then reach out to Snowflake support for best assistance.

Answer (score -1):

After browsing several hours and doing stuff like pointed in their community answers:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D53r0000BdPfQZCQ0/snowflake-how-to-connect-to-snowflake-using-nodejs

or

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-troubleshoot-Network-Error-could-not-connect-to-Snowflake-with-snowflake-sdk-nodejs-drivers

Maybe this answer can help you as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78069253/2472005

I had to add the schema value into the object passed to **createConnection** after cursing for several hours :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587